# Multivariate multiple nonlinear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, multivariate-regression

I am supposed to build a nonlinear regression model with multiple, correlated dependent variables and multiple independent variables, i.e. a multiple multivariate regression model. Unfortunately, I can hardly find any (scientific) information on the nonlinear case. - What are the arguments in favour of a multiple, multivariate nonlinear regression model? In which cases would it be adequate? How would you estimate the model using R or any standard statistics software?

I am happy to provide more information if needed! Thank you so much, any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: When you say nonlinear do you mean the predictors enter nonlinearly or do you mean you are predicting the outcome through a log, logit, or other link?

Comment: I mean that the predictors enter nonlinearly, i.e. there are interaction terms.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to do something similar.